# Какую литературу почитать по PHP, MySQL, JavaScript и Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

У меня очень хорошо получается дизайн полиграфии, сайтов, логотипов и т.д.
Знаю HTML и CSS. Хочу выучить PHP, MySQL, JavaScript и Ajax. Какую литературу вы мне посоветуете почитать. Мне сейчас 17 лет, осенью поеду в Австрию для учебы в Виенском университете, в факультете Computer Science. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ссылку на портфолио дай)

Comment: Не имею сайта и не зарегистрирован на фриланс сайтах, но уже думаю о создании своего сайта, как создам, напишу адрес.

Comment: Хм, а на основании чего в таком случае был сделан вывод, что у тебя *очень хорошо* все получается?)

Comment: я работал на реальных проектах, например полиграфический дизайн буклетов и.т.д

Comment: Ну ладно, желаю тебе всяческих успехов!

Comment: Спасибо очень :)

Comment: Мануалы и документации

Comment: Я конечно извеняюсь...А как столь ценная инфа типа - "Мне сейчас 17 лет, осенью поеду в Австрию для учебы в Виенском университете, в факультете Computer Science. " - Даст мне озарение что же дать вам почитать? :)

Comment: Назавите лучшие из них :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Касательно литературы - самое доступное и наглядное, что я видел - это серия **Head First** у издательства `O'Reilly`.

Так что смотрите в сторону [**Head First Ajax**](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596515782.do) и всех аналогичных книжек по интересующим вас темам.

Comment: Спасибо очень друг мой !