# JavaScript - с чего начать?

Tags: javascript

С чего начать изучение JS? Мне 14 лет -> Нужна какая то немудрёная книжка, ну, или уроки. Подскажите хорошую книжку или сайт с уроками по JavaScript.

Comment: С того, что не писать JavaScript раздельно

Comment: что-то чересчур много стало встречаться вопросов типа "мне Х лет. С чего начать изучать <%language_name%>?"

Comment: Гугл утверждает, что на ХК  фраза

 *с чего начать*

встречается довольно часто

    Результатов: примерно 1 590 (0,15 сек.) 

Так что, ничего нового тут нет.

--

IMHO "подсказка"

    Поиск в гугле - site:hashcode.ru Ключевые слова Вашего запроса

под полем "справка", значительно сократит количество повторяющихся вопросов.

Answer (score 8):

Дэвид Флэнаган. [JavaScript. Подробное руководство](http://www.books.ru/books/javascript-podrobnoe-rukovodstvo-6-e-izdanie-fail-pdf-1826701/?show=1).

Comment: А еще что посложнее не могли придумать для новичка-то?

Comment: На самом деле книга пугает исключительно толщиной. Читается легко, в первой части разжевано все по пунктам. Вторая половина - подробный справочник. Посередине - jQuery, HTML, CSS. В общем, мастхэв. Особенно для новичка.

Answer (score 5):

[learn.javascript.ru](http://learn.javascript.ru/)?

Comment: поддерживаю. Начинал отсюда. Хотя как новичку мне некоторые моменты были непонятны. Я бы посоветовал это комбинировать с, к примеру, видеоуроками Попова. Хоть я сам и убедился, что видеоуроки - зло, но в комбинации с хорошей теоретической базой (которую этот сайт предоставляет) будет именно то

Comment: @Vendetta8247, Попов не вариант, если нормально с английским, то лучше Крокфорд на ютубе, это, конечно, не видео-уроки, но это лучший видео-материал по JavaScript'у, во всяком случае для начинающих так точно, хотя, безусловно, для его понимания нужно обладать хотя-бы минимальными знаниями

Comment: @AlexWindHope, он объясняет на элементарнейшем уровне. С него я начинал практически всё. И некоторые основные моменты понял именно благодаря ему. Ну, как минимум, лишним не будет

Comment: @Vendetta8247, судя по вашему предыдущему вопросу, поняли вы далеко не все

Comment: @AlexWindHope, мой предыдущий вопрос относится к ассоциативным массивам и графическим элементам. Этот вопрос относится к основам. И, как я сказал выше, некоторые.

Answer (score 2):

Не-не-не!

Начните сразу писать на языке: [JavaScript на CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/ru/tracks/javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Чисто 5 копеек, я начинал так)

```
<script>
for(var i in document)
{
    document.write('<pre>' + i + '</pre><br />');
}
</script>
```

Результат выполнения особенно интересно смотреть в разных браузерах!

Answer (score 1):

Внесу свои 5 копеек: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/)

Answer (score 0):

- [Самоучители по **JavaScript**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/55401/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-javascript)
- [**JavaScript** с нуля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1842/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-javascript-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F)
- [**JavaScript** - учебник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/63304/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-javascript-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)
- [Какую литературу почитать по PHP, MySQL, **JavaScript** и Ajax?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/82368/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-php-mysql-javascript-%D0%B8-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

На youtube есть очень хорошие [видео-уроки](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6G63NKRSi8). Парень начинает с самого фундамента. То есть с инструкций и выражений. 
Если владеешь английским, то рекомендую читать блог Axel Raschmayer www.2ality.com